# windows デスクトップアプリケーションでのマウスポインター変更

Tags: c++, c

C++、C言語は初心者です。LoadCursor関数等を調べて使ってみたのですが、よく分からなかったので質問させていただきます。

どこで、どのように使えばいいのかが全く分かりません。外部参照の所のwinUser.h？等を変えるのか、こちら側で作成したゲームループ内で変えるのかがイマイチ分かってません…

Comment: 「ゲームループ」とのことですが、何らかのフレームワークを使用されていますか？ そうであればそのフレームワークに沿った方法を使用する必要がありますから、質問文で言及してください。

Comment: 上記 @sayuri さんコメントに加えて「どこで、どのように使えばいいのかが全く分かりません。」という物の前提となる「こういう状態になった時にマウスポインタをこうしたい」という実現したい事と、そのパターンが幾つぐらい存在するかといった情報が不足しています。それが無いと的確な助言や回答を得るのは難しいでしょう。